# Как правильно установить php на сервер Debian?

Tags: php, debian

Установил php на сервер, загрузил его в static файлы django, но у меня выскакивает ошибка

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

хотя файл есть на сервере, и collectstatic я сделал
Устанавливал так

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php php-fpm
обновил код nginx
server {

    # . . . other code

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score -1):

Что говорит systemctl status nginx?

Я уж не знаю предысторию php, но вычистите сначала весь php,

```
apt-get remove --purge php*
```

Затем установите нужные пакет php7.3-* из репозитория [sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/)

Больше ничего посоветовать не могу, слишком мало данных

Comment: минус за предложение загадить систему пакетами из «левого» репозитория.